# How do i start a subclass using ExpandableListView?

Tags: java, android, expandablelistview

I have an ExpandableListView that I want to set an url that an ASyncTask uses to parse a JSON depending on which child is  clicked. After setting the url it is suppose to execute and then start the subclass that shows that info with an intent. Ive tried an if statement but it wants a boolean also an experimental toast message did nothing.

Adapter:

```
public class ListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter
{

    private Activity activity;
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems;
    private LayoutInflater inflater;
    private ArrayList<String> parentItems, child;

    public ListAdapter(ArrayList<String> parents, ArrayList<Object> childern) {
        this.parentItems = parents;
        this.childItems = childern;
    }

    public void setInflater(LayoutInflater inflater, Activity activity) {
        this.inflater = inflater;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        child = (ArrayList<String>) childItems.get(groupPosition);

        TextView textView = null;

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listitems, null);
        }

        textView = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
        textView.setText(child.get(childPosition));

        convertView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(activity, child.get(childPosition),
                                   Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.listchild, null);
        }

        ((TextView) convertView).setText(parentItems.get(groupPosition));


        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return ((ArrayList<String>) childItems.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return parentItems.size();
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupCollapsed(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
        super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return 0;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return false;
    }

}
```

Class that shows expandable listview:

```
public class ShipList extends ExpandableListActivity 
{

    private ArrayList<String> parentItems = new ArrayList<String>();
    private ArrayList<Object> childItems = new ArrayList<Object>();

    private static String url = null;

    //tags for the parser here

    JSONObject arrayGetter;
    JSONArray shipStats = null;
    JSONArray hardpoints = null;

    private ProgressDialog status;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        //TextViews here

        ExpandableListView expandableList = getExpandableListView();
        expandableList.setDividerHeight(2);
        expandableList.setGroupIndicator(null);
        expandableList.setClickable(true);

        setGroupParents();
        setChildData();

        ListAdapter adapter = new ListAdapter(parentItems, childItems);

        adapter.setInflater((LayoutInflater) getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE), this);
        expandableList.setAdapter(adapter);
        expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
                {
                    /** What do I put here? Each child has different url so will likely need an if statement or switch **/
                    return true;
                }


        });


    }

    public void setGroupParents() {

        parentItems.add("Aegis Dynamics");
    }

    public void setChildData() {

        // Android
        ArrayList<String> child = new ArrayList<String>();
        child.add("Sabre");
        childItems.add(child);
    }

}
```

Main layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/shipMenu"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:groupIndicator="@null" />   

</LinearLayout>
```

Group text:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:background="@android:color/black"
    android:clickable="true"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingLeft="40dp"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="39dp"
        android:gravity="center_vertical">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView1"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
            android:textIsSelectable="true"
            android:textColor="#FFFFFF"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textStyle="bold"
            android:focusable="false"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Child:

```
<TextView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/textView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:padding="10dp"
    android:textSize="15sp"
    android:textStyle="bold"
    android:focusable="false"/>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by putting `activity.startActivity(new Intent(activity, class.class));` in the ListAdapter's onClickListener vs doing it from the activity class.

Answer (score 0):

try it..

```
expandableList.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

                @Override
                public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id)
                {
                    /** What do I put here? Each child has different url so will likely need an if statement or switch **/

                      String your_url = (String)adapter.getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);
                     // make call related to the url
                    return true;
                }


        });
```

Comment: The listener refuses to fire. No error just doesnt do anything except for displaying the toast